# Turn dataframe into list by cumulative grouping variable

Tags: r

My data:

```
set.seed(4)    
mydf <- data.frame(var1 = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=3), var2 = runif(12), grp = rep(1:4, each=3))


   var1        var2 grp
1     A 0.585800305   1
2     A 0.008945796   1
3     A 0.293739612   1
4     B 0.277374958   2
5     B 0.813574215   2
6     B 0.260427771   2
7     C 0.724405893   3
8     C 0.906092151   3
9     C 0.949040221   3
10    D 0.073144469   4
11    D 0.754675027   4
12    D 0.286000621   4
```

I want to get a list of dataframes where the first element of the list has grp=1, the second element of the list has grp<=2, and so on.  This can be done with a `for` loop:

```
results<-NULL
for(i in 1:max(mydf$grp)) {results[[i]] <- mydf[mydf$grp <= i,] }
results
```

Is there a faster way for doing this using either `dplyr` or `data.table` that I'm missing?

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Slower, by `microbenchmark`; means of about 2 vs 3 milliseconds on my machine. May be different at scale...

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Nope, I benchmarked everything, and the `for` loop holds its own (because it's so simple, I guess?). The `data.table` approach improves with data size, but still doesn't beat the loop. Everything else I tried was slower, aside from the `lapply` version below, which seems equivalent.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Nope about talking about the answer below, but it doesn't matter. Your logic makes sense, and leads me to think there might be a quicker way using `split` so `grp` doesn't have to be reevaluated each iteration, but I can't make it faster yet.

Comment: Initiating "results" as `vector("list", length(unique(mydf$grp)))` should improve efficiency. Do you need to save all these "data.frame"s at start? Perhaps, you can subset only when needed for further computations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took me ages, but I've finally got something useful. Firstly, when the data is very small (like the example), the original `for` loop is near impossible to beat. As the data gets bigger, though, the story changes dramatically. (See the end for my bigger sample data set.)

---

### `cumsum(group_size( ... ))`

Using `dplyr`'s `group_size` function, you can get a vector of the length of every level of a variable. As long as they're in order (you can use `arrange` if not), you can call `cumsum` on this to get the indices of the final rows of each subset you want. Then all you need to do is loop the subsetting.

The advantage here is that you don't need to repetitively evaluate every value in `grp` for each iteration: you can just subset by integers.

Keeping a `for` loop,

```
library(dplyr)

grps <- cumsum(group_size(group_by(mydf, grp)))
results <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(grps)){results[[i]] <- mydf[seq.int(grps[i]),]}
```

is slower for the original sample set, but starts to get faster at about 4000 rows.

Wrapping the same approach with `lapply` instead of a `for` loop

```
grps <- cumsum(group_size(group_by(mydf, grp)))
lapply(grps, function(x){mydf[seq.int(x)]})
```

produces similar results.

---

### `tbl_df`

To speed things up further, convert `mydf` to a `tbl_df`.

Even with the original approach

```
results<-NULL
mydf_t <- tbl_df(mydf)
for(i in 1:max(mydf_t$grp)) {results[[i]] <- mydf_t[mydf_t$grp <= i,] }
```

on 40k rows, this approach takes about 40-45% as long as the original.

With `cumsum(group_size())`, in `lapply`

```
grps <- cumsum(group_size(group_by(mydf, grp)))
mydf_t <- tbl_df(mydf)
lapply(grps, function(x){mydf_t[seq.int(x),]})
```

on 40k rows, this approach takes 25-30% as long as the original. In a `for` loop

```
grps <- cumsum(group_size(group_by(mydf, grp)))
results <- NULL
mydf_t <- tbl_df(mydf)
for(i in 1:length(grps)){results[[i]] <- mydf_t[seq.int(i),]}
```

on 40k rows, this approach takes 20-25% as long as the original. I have no idea *why* the `for` loop outperforms `lapply`, but it consistently does so in this case.

---

### Failed attempts

Some things that are slow, but might be able to be made fast:

- Using `split` and some version of `rbind` (`do.call(rbind, ... )`, `data.table::rbindlist`, `dplyr::bind_rows`), which seems like it *should* be fast, but isn't.
- `dplyr::slice`, which is slightly slower than normal subsetting on integers.
- `tbl_dt`. I'm not sure why it's so much slower than `tbl_df` here, but it is.

---

### Timing code

I used `microbenchmark` to compare the versions above. All in one:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark('original' = {
  results<-NULL
  for(i in 1:max(mydf$grp)) {results[[i]] <- mydf[mydf$grp <= i,] }
},
'group_size for' = {
  grps <- cumsum(group_size(group_by(mydf, grp)))
  results <- NULL
  for(i in 1:length(grps)){results[[i]] <- mydf[seq.int(grps[i]),]}
},
'group_size lapply' = {
  grps <- cumsum(group_size(group_by(mydf, grp)))
  lapply(grps, function(x){mydf[seq.int(x),]})
},
'original tbl_df' = {
  results<-NULL
  mydf_t <- tbl_df(mydf)
  for(i in 1:max(mydf_t$grp)) {results[[i]] <- mydf_t[mydf_t$grp <= i,] }
},
'tbl_df group_size lapply' = {
  grps <- cumsum(group_size(group_by(mydf, grp)))
  mydf_t <- tbl_df(mydf)
  lapply(grps, function(x){mydf_t[seq.int(x),]})
},
'tbl_df group_size for' = {
  grps <- cumsum(group_size(group_by(mydf, grp)))
  results <- NULL
  mydf_t <- tbl_df(mydf)
  for(i in 1:length(grps)){results[[i]] <-mydf_t[seq.int(grps[i]),]}
},
times = 10)
```

On 40k rows, one sample run on my machine returns:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                     expr  min   lq mean median   uq  max neval
                 original 1273 1337 1379   1395 1414 1447    10
           group_size for 1003 1111 1139   1169 1176 1211    10
        group_size lapply 1132 1153 1210   1168 1287 1306    10
          original tbl_df  457  474  560    598  608  671    10
 tbl_df group_size lapply  252  397  401    404  422  504    10
    tbl_df group_size for  279  303  375    401  421  427    10
```

**Warning:** Kind of slow if you run them all at once or raise `times` very high.

---

### Sample data

I expanded the original sample data as such up to 4k, 10k, and 40k rows. Adjust the numbers how you like.

```
set.seed(4)    
mydf <- data.frame(var1 = sort(sample(LETTERS, 40000, replace = TRUE)), 
                   var2 = runif(40000), 
                   grp = rep(1:400, each=100))
```

**Warning:** When `mydf` is 40k rows, the loops above produce a dataset that is 123.5 Mb.

Comment: Note that the times above are pretty variable depending on your processor's mood, so take the percentages above with a spoonful of salt. The order of speed seems fairly consistent, though, with the `tbl_df group_size for` and `lapply` always significantly faster than the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Try a `lapply` statement:

```
set.seed(4)    
mydf <- data.frame(
    var1 = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=3), 
    var2 = runif(12), 
    grp = rep(1:4, each=3))

ptm <- proc.time()

results<-NULL
for(i in 1:max(mydf$grp)) {results[[i]] <- mydf[mydf$grp <= i,] }
results

proc.time() - ptm
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.029   0.001   0.057 

ptm <- proc.time()
q <- lapply(unique(mydf$grp), function(x) mydf[mydf$grp <= x,])
proc.time() - ptm

#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.007   0.001   0.034
```

Comment: Using `microbenchmark`, it looks like this is about the same speed.

Comment: Re-running it, the mean times trade off for who's faster. I tried scaling up `mydf`, with similar results for dimensions as big as I was willing to wait for.